# Recursive postgres query to view

Tags: postgresql, recursion

I have the following table which models a very simple hierarchical data structure with each element pointing to its parent:

```
                                     Table "public.device_groups"
    Column    |          Type          |                           Modifiers                           
--------------+------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------
 dg_id        | integer                | not null default nextval('device_groups_dg_id_seq'::regclass)
 dg_name      | character varying(100) | 
 dg_parent_id | integer                |
```

I want to query the recursive list of subgroups of a specific group.

I constructed the following recursive query which works fine:

```
WITH RECURSIVE r(dg_parent_id, dg_id, dg_name) AS (
    SELECT dg_parent_id, dg_id, dg_name FROM device_groups WHERE dg_id=1
  UNION ALL
    SELECT dg.dg_parent_id, dg.dg_id, dg.dg_name
    FROM r pr, device_groups dg
    WHERE dg.dg_parent_id = pr.dg_id
  )
SELECT dg_id, dg_name
FROM r;
```

I now want to turn this into a view **where I can choose which group I want to drill down for using a WHERE clause**. This means I want to be able to do:

```
SELECT * FROM device_groups_recursive WHERE dg_id = 1;
```

And get all the (recursive) subgroups of the group with id 1

I was able to write a function (by wrapping the query from above), but I would like to have a view instead of the function.

*Side-Node: I know of the shortcoming of an adjacency list representation, I cannot change it currently.*

Comment: In the view definition just omit the `WHERE dg_id=1` . The dg_id is exposed by the view, so when *using* the view, the *user* could do `select * from the_view tv WHERE tv.dg_id=1` from the outer select (or join)

Comment: I highly doubt that you'd get the same results that way. The first query is just for the "top" level row.. subsequent rows will not have dg_id=1. The fix will be to either do a (very likely MUCH less efficient ) rewrite, OR, write this as a stored function returning a  table.